# Execute an Ajax request every second

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call being made to a php file. I am receiving results. Now I am investigating if it is possible to have the ajax request automatically perform every 1 second. I am posting the results into input field called `hidden`. How can I execute the ajax call every three seconds without having to call the function?

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'increment.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#hidden').val(data);// first set the value     

            }
    });
```

Comment: *"Execute an Ajax request every second"* No, please don't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know its not good practice. It is just for learning cause.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something you might want to consider is [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) (SSE's)

This is an HTML5 technology whereby Javascript will "[long-poll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)" a server endpoint (your PHP file) to see if any changes have occurred. Long-polling is basically where JS (I'm not sure if it uses Ajax or another technology) sends a request every second to the endpoint

You can try it like this:

```
#/your_js
var evtSource = new EventSource("increment.php");
evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    $('#hidden').val(e.data);
}
```

To send the data, you can make an ajax call which will send the updated JSON object to the server, like you have:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".your_object", function(data) {
     $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'increment.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json'
        });
   });
```

This will only open an Ajax request when you perform an event, and your app will be "listening" for the response every second. As you are aware, Ajax long-polling is super resource-intensive, so it will be better to look at web-socket stuff if you want true "real-time" technology, but either way, this will be a much more efficient system than just using plain ajax for everything

A caveat here -- you'll have to change your `increment.php` to handle the different response types

Comment: I can elaborate more if this is something you're interested in

Comment: Very Nice, I was not aware of this. I keep checking the `increment.php` for the number of current rows in a table. I will read more into this

Comment: +1 interesting to have a HTML5 solution.

Comment: I worked with SSE's when we were trying to create some real-time notifications in one of our apps. It felt like a mine-field at first, but it's actually quite simple to do, especially if you're using a framework. If not, it's still quite simple to deploy

Comment: Very interesting, but it seems IE/Edge still doesn't support it as of [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource)

Answer (score 50):

You can do this with a repeated series of `setTimeout` calls. (**Don't** use `setInterval`  with `ajax` calls, you'll get chaos in no time; `setInterval` will fire off the next ajax call even if the previous one hasn't completed yet.)

Use `setTimeout` to schedule the first call, and then when it completes to schedule the next, etc.:

```
var interval = 1000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 3000 = 3 seconds
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'increment.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#hidden').val(data);// first set the value     
            },
            complete: function (data) {
                    // Schedule the next
                    setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
            }
    });
}
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
```

Note that I'm using `complete`, not `success`, to schedule the next call, so that an interruption (temporary drop in your 'net connection, whatever) doesn't kill the process.

Comment: Now it makes more sense why to use `setTimeout` over `setInterval`.

Comment: Could you replace `complete` with `always` since the old one is now deprecated?

Comment: @Dharman - You worried me for a second there, I thought "surely they can't have deprecated *that*?!" And [they haven't](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). The `complete` **option** (used above) is not deprecated. The `complete` *method* on the `jqXHR` object `ajax` returns (not used above) is deprecated. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Yes possible using **`setInterval`**

1) Keep your ajax within a function.

```
function fun() {
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'increment.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                    $('#hidden').val(data);// first set the value     

            }
    });
}
```

2) Now using `setInterval`, you can execute it every second.

```
var interval = setInterval(fun, 1000);
```

3) To pause/clear use `clearInterval`

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

4) As other pointed that using `setInterval` for **`ajax`** is not wise, so try using

```
var interval;
function callAjax() {
  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'increment.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                        $('#hidden').val(data);// first set the value 
                        interval = setTimeout(callAjax, 1000);   
                }
        });
}
callAjax();
//clearTimeout(interval);
```

Comment: True, yet I'd prefer using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` so you don't get overlapping requests even though the server is a bit slow at executing the backend.

Comment: When using `ajax`, **definitely** use repeated `setTimeout` (schedule the next when the previous completes) rather than `setInterval`. With `setInterval` and ajax requests, you'll get chaos.

Comment: Your `setTimeout` example results in a total of two calls to the function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry for that.  I got the mistake I have done.  I have corrected it.  But +1 for letting us to know about `complete` callback.  Very wise solution.  Thank you.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan If you set `interval` inside the anonymous function, you might as well not set it. Either declare the variable in the global scope or don't bother declaring it at all. It's also `clearTimeout(interval)` and not `clearTimeout(fun)`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Missed it.  Thank you, for pointing my mistakes.