# Stopping a recurring ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an app where there's loads of products, each with a button. My plan is the user clicks one of the buttons and I have a javascript (jquery) function which starts making an ajax request every second using the id of the button as a parameter to identify the product.

The function I'm planning on using is the 2nd answer here [Execute an Ajax request every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371695/execute-an-ajax-request-every-second)

The idea is to check the status of the product (which can change constantly) every second while the user is interested in it.

When the user clicks the button again I want to stop checking this particular product's status but I can't figure out how to do this. In my head I imagine the user might have clicked 3 buttons so there's 3 ajax requests every second happening, each with a different product id. How can I stop the recurring request which has the id of the product the user has clicked stop?

Comment: Without a code we can't help you

Comment: I so wanted to put a comment here that just said "42". Can you share, other than a link, what you have tried? Using `setInterval()` you can always use `clearInterval()` to stop a named interval.

Comment: The question you reference was "just for practice" they said. Calling a service every second, per user, is a really bad idea. Maybe signal-R for comms server=>client instead?

Comment: Do what Jay Blanchard said or use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) and [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout) if you chose some code from that link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently, where I had an interval running every few seconds and, when some event occurred, I stopped the process altogether. I'm assuming you're using Javascript, so something like the below. You can check "someVar" in the timer call if you wish, up to you...

```
   var someVar = false, intervalId;
    $(function () {
        // Attach event handler to button
        $('#ButtonId').click(function (e) {
            if (!someVar) {
                e.preventDefault();
                someVar = true;
                //Start interval
                intervalId = setInterval(CheckStatus, 3000);
            } else {
                // Stop the interval!
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                someVar = false;
            }
        });
    });

    function CheckStatus() {
        // I used MVC, but you can use whatever you need to generate the URL
        var checkUrl = '@Url.Action("CheckStatus", "SomeController", new { intervalId = "_intervalId_" })'.replace('_intervalId_', intervalId).replace(/&amp;/g, "&");

        $.ajax({
            url: checkUrl,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                // do something with the status - data.Status perhaps?
            },
            error: function () {
                //handle error
            }
        });
    }
```