# in ajax autorefresh with passing variable.. don't no to pass variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jsp

I have a chat box..
In that 2 frames
One frames display all the user name...
2nd frame we get full chat of the user u click from frame one...

Now I need to reload frame2 Everytime to check whter I got msg from sender...
I can use autorefresh here...
BT my problem is.. how to pass a variable on function call....

// Function call

Function call ( parameter)

//Ajax call to get all msg of clicked user and display in second frame

Now I need to reload or auto refresh it every 5 second 
Plz help

Comment: onclick=fun(userid1).         onclick=fun(userid1).  Function(I'd) {. Ajax call }

Comment: Please edit your question to include that logic in it, rather than as a comment.  The edit link is under the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute an ajax request every x seconds timeouts could be interesting for you:

```
var interval = 1000;  // 1000 = 1 second, 5000 = 5 seconds
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                    // do whatever you want
            }
      });
}
setInterval(doAjax, interval);
```

---

Links for more information:

W3Schools  [timeouts](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Another good StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20371695/execute-an-ajax-request-every-second)

---

Hope I could help!